# I Can't views orders magento 2.3

Tags: magento2, orders, backend

[image]

Hi, I try to view the order in backend and show me this error, I need help to fix it

Comment: On the surface Javascript error. Anything in console log?

Comment: negative, javascript not show me a error in console

Answer (score 0):

you can try below way.. 
Disabling **Temando_Shipping** Module fixes the issue.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/159636)

Comment: @MohitKumarArora i know but this Issue facing  many user  so i have add here

Comment: While asking a question or answering, everyone is expected to either explain more or there is an option to comment on the post.

Comment: This isn't fixes that, i disable that module and the problem persist

Comment: @emmanuelortega you have run command ? like upgrade,compile

Comment: of course, but doesn't function